# How to find question about a specific kind of personal statement?

Tags: discussion, tags, search

So the a tag for the specific kind of personal statement has been synonymized to the [sop](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sop) tag*. This is the decision of the community, and I have no objection. I just want to know if there is a way to quickly find the questions I need, or there is no way to filter them? To quote myself:

> For those who fall into the situation like me, the feeling of having a distinction is very clear. It's also a big plus for future visitors who only want to read questions about this.

*[Should statement-of-purpose tag be synonyms with personal-statement?](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2114/14341)

Comment: If the feeling of distinction is clear to you, can you please explain it?  I do not see any clear distinction myself.

Comment: @jakebeal which part you don't see it's clear? You can comment on my answer there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most personal statements that I've encountered are also about research, and how does this fit with teaching statements? I guess my feeling is that this is a confusing, nation- and institution-dependent definition with no clear standards or terminology, and I'm not sure you're going to be able to narrow things down any better than they are without also excluding things you'd want to read.